# What are crowds like in Banff and Jasper in July?

Tags: canada, planning, nature-and-wildlife, national-parks, alberta

I am planning a trip to Banff and/or Jasper in mid-late July. I am unfamiliar with the area and in early stages of planning.

My question is, what are the crowds like in the towns/parks at that time of year? Having worked in Yellowstone and visited Yosemite on July 4th (insane traffic!, overflowing campsites!), I was just curious about the scale of visitors, tours, etc.

Is traffic in issue moving around/between the parks? Is it necessary to hit popular trails early in the morning to avoid crowds?

Answer (score 5):

Banff and Jasper are no different than Yellowstone in terms of summer traffic. Campgrounds, hotels fill early, lots of folks enjoying the sights and trails.  Plenty of traffic on the road between the two.